# A problem related to Ultrafilter.

Tags: general-topology, filters

If every ultrafilter $\mathcal F$ in $X$ containing $A \subseteq X$ also contains $B\subseteq X$, then I have to show that $A\subset B$.

Any insight.
I was using the fact  that if $C \cup D \in \mathcal F$ then either $C \in \mathcal F$ or $ D\in \mathcal F$ , where $\mathcal F$ is any ultrafilter. From this condition here in my problem $C= A$ and $D= B$ and  $A\cup B = A$ or $B$ (as either $A \in \mathcal F$ or $B \in \mathcal F$). And I have to show that it's $B$, Here I got stuck.
Hope to get a help.
**Thank You.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $A$ and $A\setminus B$. If $A\setminus B$ is non-empty, then $\{A,A\setminus B\}$ has the finite intersection property, therefore can be extended to an ultrafilter. What can you say about such ultrafilter?

Comment: I think. that ultrafilter will not contain $B$ .

Comment: But can you prove that?

Comment: I think {$A$ ,$A\setminus B$} will be a subbase for a filter,and the filter will consist of the supersets of intersection of $A$ and $A \setminus B$ which is $A \setminus B$ , so the filter doesn't contain $B$ and hence this filter is contained in an ultrafilter which will not contain $B$ also.

Comment: Yes, that is correct (modulo $\rm\LaTeX$ issues ;-))

Comment: Yes, I am not very smooth in Latex..

Comment: So that ultrafilter will contain $A $ but not $B$ , hence a contradiction, so it must $A \cup B $ = $B$ , right ?

Comment: Yes, because it means that $\{A,A\setminus B\}$ is *not* a filter base, which can only be the case when $A\setminus B$ is empty.

Answer (score 2):

If $p\in A$ \ $B$ then $F=\{C: p\in C\subset X\}$ is an ultra-filter on $X$ and $p\in A\subset X$ so  $A\in F$, but $B\not \in F$ because $p\in X$ \ $B\subset X\implies X$ \ $B\in F$.